# Trying to use Uploadify in an MVC3 application what is the problem?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

Why doesn't the file input element show up at all??? see code and screen shot below.  I've spent the last few hours researching this on every forum I can find.  I cannot get a consistent answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>

    Home Page

</title><link href="mvc3/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/mvc3/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/mvc3/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/mvc3/uploadify/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery("#dr405").uploadify({
                    'uploader': 'uploadify.swf',
                    'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
                    'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
                    'script': 'Uploader.ashx',
                    'folder': 'uploads',
                    'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                    'multi': true,
                    'auto': true
                });
            }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">

        Welcome <strong>dougrchamberlain</strong>!
        [ <a href="/mvc3/Account/LogOff">Log Off</a> ]

            </div> 
            <div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="/mvc3/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/mvc3/Home/About">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">

    <h2>Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!</h2>

    <p>Please upload your return</p>   
    <input type="file" name="dr405" id="dr405" />


            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**Update**

After fixing the url references. To actually point to the files in question, here is what I am seeing on my end.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url to the `uploadify.swf` looks wrong. I would recommend you always using URL helpers when dealing with urls:

```
jQuery("#dr405").uploadify({
    'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/mvc3/uploadify/uploadify.swf")',
    'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
    ...
});
```

Comment: What is this new cryptic syntax with MVC3?  where can I find a reference for when to use @ and such.  That looks like it wouldn't work to me.  But it must be doing some sort of replacement?

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain, that's [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx), the new view engine from Microsoft. If you are still using WebForms the equivalent syntax is `<%= Url.Content("~/mvc3/uploadify/uploadify.swf") %>`

Comment: You sir are smart.  I've updated my question.  Now I'm just getting a generic error message.

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain, when is this error thrown? Is the server side upload handler that you specified `Uploader.ashx` being hit? Is the url to this handler correct? Try using an url helper to specify the path to this handler. If you type the url to this handler directly in the browser address bar does it work?

Comment: I pointed back to the .php file and ran it using IIS7.5 with PHP installed.  It worked!!! woot!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, although I was not using an ashx.  The problem was that I wasn't referencing my controller's method correctly.  My controller is named FileController.cs so instead of 'script': 'FileController/Upload', I used 'script':'File/Upload' and now no more IO Error - it calls the function in the controller correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'uploader': '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': '/File/Upload',
        'cancelImg': '/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'multi': true,
        'auto': true,
        'buttonText': 'SELECT',
        'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + queueID + " .percentage").text(' - Completed');
            return false;
         }
    });
});
```

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
    {
        var fileName = this.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
        fileData.SaveAs(fileName);
        return "ok";
    }
```